# XSL-FO fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives not working properly

Tags: xslt, pagination, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to add the page number in footer if the number of pages is more than one, but not for if there is only one page.

I tried the following code but it shows the page number in all cases :

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="singlePage" page-height="800pt" page-width="612pt" margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="46pt" margin-left="26pt" margin-right="26pt">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="110pt" margin-bottom="65pt" />
                <fo:region-before extent="72pt" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after-single" extent="75pt" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>

            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="multiPage" page-height="800pt" page-width="612pt" margin-top="0pt" margin-bottom="46pt" margin-left="26pt" margin-right="26pt">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="110pt" margin-bottom="65pt" />
                <fo:region-before extent="72pt" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after-multi" extent="75pt" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>

            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="allPages">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                   <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="any" master-reference="multiPage"/>
                   <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="only" master-reference="singlePage"/>
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="allPages">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block>content</fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after-single">
                <fo:block>content</fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after-multi">
                    <fo:block>content</fo:block>
                    <fo:block text-align="right">
                        <fo:inline><fo:page-number font-weight="normal"/>/<fo:page-number-citation ref-id = "lastPage"/></fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="12pt" line-height="11pt">
                <fo:block>content</fo:block>
                <fo:block id = "lastPage"/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
```

If I change the order of alternatives, then page number is never shown:

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="allPages">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="only" master-reference="singlePage"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="any" master-reference="multiPage"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

I'm using FOP 2.0

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second alternative works for me with both FOP 2.0 and FOP 2.2:

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="allPages">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="only" master-reference="singlePage"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="any" master-reference="multiPage"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

Did you try it with enough content to make a second page?  E.g., add `<fo:block break-before="page">content</fo:block>` to force a second page.

If you change the 'content' text in your `fo:static-content` for the `fo:region-after` then you'll get a better idea of which `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` is being used; e.g.:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after-single">
   <fo:block>after single</fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

The way that `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_conditional-page-master-reference) works is that it is selected if it is the first alternative for which all of its sub-conditions are true.  If there is enough content to make a second page, then the `page-position="only"` sub-condition is no longer true, so the formatter should try again with other alternatives.

The formatter should try again because if it doesn't, then the `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_repeatable-page-master-alternatives) doesn't satisfy its constraints (my emphasis):

> The sub-sequence of pages mapped to this sub-sequence-specifier satisfies the constraints of this sub-sequence-specifier if (a) the sub-sequence of pages consists of zero or more pages, (b) each page is generated using the fo:simple-page-master referenced by the one of the alternatives that are the children of the fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives, (c) **the conditions on that alternative are true**, (d) that alternative is the first alternative in the sequence of children for which all the conditions are true, and (e) the length of the sub-sequence is less than or equal to the value of 'maximum-repeats'.